# How to setup portable Firefox using selenium/python on windows?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, portability

I've tried this python script to open a url in portable Firefox on windows, but I get `SessionNotCreatedException` traceback.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('path\\to\\FirefoxPortable32.exe')
exec_path = "path\\to\\geckodriver32.exe"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=exec_path, firefox_binary=binary)
browser.get('some_url')
```

Here's the traceback:

> File "tst.py", line 20, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=exec_path, firefox_binary=binary)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 174, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 252, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) 
>   selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable
>   to find a matching set of capabilities

I am using:

```
windows 7 (64 bit)
python 3.7
selenium 3.141
geckdriver v0.24.0 (64 bit)
FirefoxPortable 68.0.1 (64 bit)
```

Any idea how to get the portable Firefox working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the path to Firefox binary to the firefox.exe file inside "App" folder.
E.g. `'path\\to\\FirefoxPortable\\App\\Firefox\\firefox.exe'`

Comment: If you need Firefox 64-bit version, then use this path inside "App" folder. 'path\\to\\FirefoxPortable\\App\\Firefox64\\firefox.exe'